# How to create sequence diagram using UMLet with the java code

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, sequence-diagram, umlet

I was trying to create UML Diagram using UMLet. The tutorial shows the examples where I need to start creating it form scratch. But I need to create UML diagram for an already existing code. It gives the class attributes for a particular class, but how can I create an activity diagram or a sequence diagram for an existing code with UMLet?

Comment: Thank you for the info on one more tool. +1 and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

### Not such option here!

The only back engineering tool for sequence diagrams that I know, is [UMLgraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/). You need a license for it, but it is time-limited free, as I understand. It is for Eclipse and can be installed easily enough. And Class diagrams back engineering is without licenses. I have checked them - class diagrams really do that back engineering.

Also, look seriously at Papyrus. It is powerful, and not worse than the best proprietary tools.

As for Umlet, it "produces sequence and activity diagrams from plain text" (and class diagrams, too). It simply has text-diagram equivalence, so you edit text and get diagram. It does not do any sequence diagrams from Java code. It simply has not such option. It is much, much, much more simple tool! It declares that it can do some class diagrams from Java, but the option is unusable in the current version.